# TargetInvocationException Scaffold-DbContext EF 5

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am trying to run the following scaffold the project is in .net 5. and I get this error

All my projects say

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
```

The one project that references efcore

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="5.0.4" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Abstractions" Version="5.0.4" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Analyzers" Version="5.0.4" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational" Version="5.0.4" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="5.0.4" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="5.0.4">
```

Error

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
 ---> System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.SemanticVersionComparer' from assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=5.0.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor..ctor(IOperationReportHandler reportHandler, IDictionary args)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Object[] args)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.ReflectionOperationExecutor..ctor(String assembly, String startupAssembly, String projectDir, String dataDirectory, String rootNamespace, String language, String[] remainingArguments)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Commands.ProjectCommandBase.CreateExecutor(String[] remainingArguments)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Commands.DbContextScaffoldCommand.Execute(String[] args)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Commands.CommandBase.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>b__0(String[] args)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.CommandLine.CommandLineApplication.Execute(String[] args)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Program.Main(String[] args)
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
```

Saffold Command

> Scaffold-DbContext "Server=1.1.1.1,1433;Initial Catalog=First;Persist
> Security Info=False;User
> ID=data;Password=data;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=True;Connection
> Timeout=30;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir
> Model/DB -Force -Context S3Context -Project S3.Core.DataSync.Framework
> -t Data,SyncSales

Comment: Are you mixing versions? Please share your .csproj contents

Comment: please see revised question

Answer (score 1):

I have 3 projects 1 project containing EF Core. If I load all three projects and set the project that has references to EF Core as "Set as Startup" I no longer have this issue. As soon as I set what should be the the startup project I get this error